# Bat file open file after command is run

Tags: rspec, batch-file, cmd

So I have this command that creates a file, would like to auto open the file after the command is done... I've tried this:

```
start /b /wait rspec spec --drb --format html --out doc/rspec_out.html
echo DONE
start doc/rspec_out.html
```

But once the first command finishes, the second command doesn't appear to run (I don't see `DONE`).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: The batch file looks fine, can you run this in a cmd prompt and see if the command finishes?

Comment: Is `rspec` a batch file?

Comment: i don't think it's a batch file, but it runs and then finishes... when i run it in cmd the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rspec` is a batch file, either of the following should help:

Adding the `EXIT` command at the end (the exit point) of the `rspec` script.

Running the first command like this:

```
start /b /wait cmd.exe /c "rspec spec --drb --format html --out doc/rspec_out.html"
```

Comment: I guess it's because `rspec` *was* a batch file after all. I also guess that you tried executing *your* script from the command prompt. This is what likely happened. `start` called a new instance of `cmd` to execute `rspec`. If you hadn't used the `/b` option, you'd have seen the new `cmd` session open in a separate window, but `/b` made it open in the same window as the original `cmd` session. When `rspec` finished its job, the new session didn't close automatically (because `rspec` didn't end with `exit`). ...

Comment: You could issue `exit` manually from the command prompt, and that would close the new session and bring you back to the session where *your* script was invoked, and you would see your script go on executing.